# How to Force Windows to Start a Process as an EXE

Tags: c#, .net, process

If possible, how would you force C# code to run any given file as an exe even when the extension isn't `.exe`?

For example, my code extracts an exe from the program's resources into the user's roaming folder and starts it; `GetRandomFileName()` returns XXXXXX.XXX with Xs being random characters, but if I try to do:

```
string exePath = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\" + Path.GetRandomFileName();

using (FileStream exeFile = new FileStream(exePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
                            exeFile.Write(exeBytes, 0, exeBytes.Length);

process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
processStartInfo.FileName = exePath;
Process.Start();
```

I get an error as Windows tries launching the program as a .XXX (whatever the random file extension may be).

Image of the error given:
[image]

Comment: Just rename it to `.exe`.

Comment: I considered that but I'd like for it to be completely random and start as an exe. If this is the only workaround I can do that but I'd like to wait and see if it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set `UseShellExecute` to `false`:

```cs
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
processStartInfo.FileName = exePath;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start();
```

By default, `Process` will use the Windows Shell to try to start your file. The Shell looks at the extension to figure out which program should actually run. Known-executable files are run directly, but any other file is checked for file extension associations. If none is present, you get the prompt to find a program to run it.

You can bypass all of that by setting `UseShellExecute` to `false`. That forces the `Process` class to just use the native `CreateProcess()` function directly. That function doesn't have any trouble starting any valid executable file, regardless of file name.